From getElementById to getElementsByClassName and get same result?
Looking at the code below, you will notice when I click the arrow icons an "Added!" text will appear in green to the left, but in one spot only.
I want the "Added!" text to appear next to each arrow icon, for each icon that is clicked, without removing the fade/animations.
(Example:
If I click the top arrow icon, text will appear and fade to the left of that only; if I click the middle arrow icon only, text appears and fades to the left of that icon only; if I click the bottom arrow icon, text appears and fades to the left of that icon only)
How can I achieve this? Do I need to change the ID elements to Class elements? (I am willing to use whatever code works as long as it keeps the fade/animations).


  function showAdded() {
    let message = document.getElementById('notification-text');

    if (message.classList.contains('noDisplay')) {
      message.classList.remove('noDisplay');
    }

    // message.classList.add('noDisplay');
    message.style.animation = 'none';
    message.offsetHeight;
    message.style.animation = null;
  }
  .shopping-cart-add-on {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Plus_symbol.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 29px 29px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-radius: 24px;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    left: 124px;
    transition: all .3s;
  }

  #notification-text {
    position: absolute;
    text-wrap: nowrap;
    animation-name: msgSuccess;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 4ms;
    color: green;
  }

  .noDisplay {
    display: none;
  }

  @keyframes msgSuccess {
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    99% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
    }
  }
  <br>

  <div class="shopping-cart-add-on" onclick="showAdded()" style="height: 28px; width: 28px"></div>
  <div id="notification-text" class="noDisplay">Added!</div>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <div class="shopping-cart-add-on" onclick="showAdded()" style="height: 28px; width: 28px"></div>
  <div id="notification-text" class="noDisplay">Added!</div>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <div class="shopping-cart-add-on" onclick="showAdded()" style="height: 28px; width: 28px"></div>
  <div id="notification-text" class="noDisplay">Added!</div>
  </div>




Yes I would update your ids to classes and use document.querySelectorAll(".notification-text"). ids should be unique within a document.

By the way, you don't need the classList.contains call in there; remove won't try to remove non-existent classes, and won't throw any errors if the class is not present.

showAdded() needs an argument that indicates which div you clicked on. Then you can use div.querySelector(".notification-text") to find the corresponding notification element.

Thank you for your comments everyone! Very helpful, and I will experiment and implement!

Change from id="notification-text" to class="notification-text".
Add a parameter to the showAdded() function to tell it which div you clicked on. Then you can find the nested notification-text element within that.
You also had extra </div> tags that were ending the shopping-cart-add-on divs prematurely, instead of wrapping them around the notification divs.


function showAdded(div) {
  let message = div.querySelector('.notification-text');

  message.classList.remove('noDisplay');

  // message.classList.add('noDisplay');
  message.style.animation = 'none';
  message.offsetHeight;
  message.style.animation = null;
}
.shopping-cart-add-on {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Plus_symbol.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 29px 29px;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  left: 124px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.notification-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  animation-name: msgSuccess;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 4ms;
  color: green;
}

.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes msgSuccess {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
<br>

<div class="shopping-cart-add-on" onclick="showAdded(this)" style="height: 28px; width: 28px">
  <div class="notification-text" class="noDisplay">Added!</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="shopping-cart-add-on" onclick="showAdded(this)" style="height: 28px; width: 28px">
  <div class="notification-text" class="noDisplay">Added!</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="shopping-cart-add-on" onclick="showAdded(this)" style="height: 28px; width: 28px">
  <div class="notification-text" class="noDisplay">Added!</div>
</div>




By wrapping the  around the notification divs, the notification divs take on the .shopping-cart-add-on CSS... is there anyway to wrap the  around the notification divs without taking on the .shopping-cart-add-on div CSS? I want the notification-text CSS and the shopping-cart-add-on CSS distinct from each other.

Previous comment solution: Adding "pointer-events: none" to .notification-text  CSS seemed to solve the issue of the child div inheriting the parent div

Instead of wrapping the div around the notification div, you can put one before the other. Then you can use div.nextElementSibling to get the notification div.

When I was fixing your invalid HTML I had to make a guess at what you intended. I assumed it supposed to wrap.

Yes, I know you can only go by what is given to you, which I appreciate. I didn't want to post my entire project so I tried to give a similar example. Thanks again!
